# AngularJs and Laravel api - how to prevent usage outsite my site

Tags: angularjs, api, security

I have a backend built in Laravel 5.2 and the frontend built in AngularJS.

The site have a list of events and it make a `GET` request to the backend to get all the events.

How can I prevent that someone use my API to get the events on other site or via mobile app?
I want that the endpoint is accessibile only form my frontend.

Is this possibile?
What should I check?
API key is the way?

Answer (score 1):

Use [OAuth2](http://oauth.net/2/). Most popular nowadays i think.

> OAuth 2.0 focuses on client developer simplicity while providing
> specific authorization flows for web applications, desktop
> applications, mobile phones, and living room devices. This
> specification is being developed within the IETF OAuth WG and is based
> on the OAuth WRAP proposal.

Here you have some extensive [documentation](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/tree/master/docs#readme) how to use OAuth2 with Laravel.

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
> between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.

There are many supported [grant types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3) in the OAuth2:

1. Authorization Code

> The authorization code is obtained by using an authorization server
> as an intermediary between the client and resource owner.  Instead of
> requesting authorization directly from the resource owner, the client
> directs the resource owner to an authorization server (via its
> user-agent as defined in [RFC2616]), which in turn directs the
> resource owner back to the client with the authorization code.

3. Resource Owner Password Credentials

> The resource owner password credentials (i.e., username and password)
> can be used directly as an authorization grant to obtain an access
> token.  The credentials should only be used when there is a high
> degree of trust between the resource owner and the client (e.g., the
> client is part of the device operating system or a highly privileged
> application), and when other authorization grant types are not
> available (such as an authorization code).

4. Client Credentials

> The client credentials (or other forms of client authentication) can
> be used as an authorization grant when the authorization scope is
> limited to the protected resources under the control of the client,
> or to protected resources previously arranged with the authorization
> server.  Client credentials are used as an authorization grant
> typically when the client is acting on its own behalf (the client is
> also the resource owner) or is requesting access to protected
> resources based on an authorization previously arranged with the
> authorization server.

1. Refresh Token

> Refresh tokens are credentials used to obtain access tokens.  Refresh
> tokens are issued to the client by the authorization server and are
> used to obtain a new access token when the current access token
> becomes invalid or expires, or to obtain additional access tokens
> with identical or narrower scope (access tokens may have a shorter
> lifetime and fewer permissions than authorized by the resource
> owner).  Issuing a refresh token is optional at the discretion of the
> authorization server.  If the authorization server issues a refresh
> token, it is included when issuing an access token (i.e., step (D) in
> Figure 1).

3. Access Token

> Access tokens are credentials used to access protected resources.  An
> access token is a string representing an authorization issued to the
> client.  The string is usually opaque to the client.  Tokens
> represent specific scopes and durations of access, granted by the
> resource owner, and enforced by the resource server and authorization
> server.

4. Implicit

> The implicit grant is a simplified authorization code flow optimized
> for clients implemented in a browser using a scripting language such
> as JavaScript.  In the implicit flow, instead of issuing the client
> an authorization code, the client is issued an access token directly
> (as the result of the resource owner authorization).  The grant type
> is implicit, as no intermediate credentials (such as an authorization
> code) are issued (and later used to obtain an access token).

Comment: Thanks @Vardius, the list is public, is not related to a specific user. Do I really need Oauth2 for this simple task?

Comment: You can use Client grant type.

Answer (score 0):

what you are mentioning is called Cross-Site Request Forgery [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) to prevent it is using Header parameter specific for your server the stander name for it is X-Requested-With.

> This header cannot be sent cross-domain via AJAX due to this header not being in the safe list (without CORS being enabled on your server). A HTML form cannot send this header either.

check this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44394/how-to-stop-other-websites-from-sending-cross-domain-ajax-requests)

if you want to use OAuth you can use client grant type as you are telling there is no user specific data, but I don't think it is the best answer for this situation.